# Adding package to laravel on live server

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I have a Laravel project on a live server and I need to add a package to it in order to make new edits. How do I install this package online?

Comment: Same way you'd install it anywhere else. `composer require` command. If you're downtime sensitive, you may want to install it locally on a development copy, deploy the resulting `composer.lock` to production, and do `composer install` instead. It's much faster.

Comment: Many thanks , after installing it locally i have just replace the vendor folder from the live server with the new vendor folder from local server ,now every thing is OK  .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install a package on laravel by adding package name to composer.json file and then run the `composer update` command.

On a live server you can use ssh to run commands.

For mac and linux: use terminal to run commands using ssh
For windows: use putty to run commands using ssh

Comment: Many thanks , after installing it locally i have just replace the vendor folder from the live server with the new vendor folder from local server ,now every thing is OK